# $.each([collection]) vs $([collection]).each()

Tags: jquery, json, iteration

Both methods appear to [produce the same results](http://jsbin.com/owedo/), but I've been hard-pressed to actually convince people that the second method works, since it's apparently not commonly known.

```
// Create some data
var foo = { 'vals':[ {'id':'foo'}, {'id':'bar'} ] }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;

// Common Method    
$.each(foo.vals, function(i,o){
    alert(this.id);
});

// Alternative (lesser-known?) Method
$(foo.vals).each(function(i,o){
   alert(this.id); 
});
```

Upon checking the source, these two appear to be one-in-the-same. The second method follows:

```
each: function( callback, args ) {
  return jQuery.each( this, callback, args );
}
```

This method demonstrably calls the more commonly-known method, meaning it's just as legitimate. Is this understanding correct, or am I missing something here?

I have typically trusted this method since it didn't cause me to deviate from standard practices with regards to selectors. Let's face it, we're trained to do:

```
$("p").each();
```

So it seems only natural to do:

```
$(obj).each();
```

Am I mistaken?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. `$(o).each()` calls `jQuery.each(this, callback, args)`. What more confirmation/convincing do you need?

Comment: @voyager: I just want to be sure I didn't have that mistaken. I figured an item like this may be of interest to other jQuery developers, and somebody may be able to add a bit to the distinction.

Comment: fair enough. It seems that the difference is more of a matter of style rather than functionality. Of course, now you have somewhere to point unconvinced users to.

Comment: @voyager: Perhaps you should bring that point into an answer ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between the two is actually exponential depending on how you are using it.

The first `$.each` constitutes a *single* function call to start the iterator.

The second `$(foo.vals).each` makes *three* function calls to start the iterator. The first is to the `$()` which produces a new jQuery wrapper set (Not sure how many other function calls are made during this process). Then the call to `$().each`. And finally it makes the internal call to `jQuery.each` to start the iterator.

In your example, the difference would be negligible to say the least. However, in a nested use scenario, you might find performance becoming an issue.

Finally, Cody Lindley in jQuery Enlightenment does not recommend using `$.each` for iterations greater than 1000 because of the function calls involved. Use a normal `for( var i = 0...` loop.

Comment: +1 Excellent information. I was especially happy to hear CL's position on the subject as I suggested `for(;;)` as an alternative to `$.each()` recently in another question. Makes me feel smart knowing that CL could have possibly agreed with me ;)

Comment: What about the reason that $.wach allows you to iterate over   any collection while the `$().each`  is only for jquery element ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what everybody else says...but I almost exclusively use your second method there.

Coming from .NET land...it just makes more sense to me and makes things easier to read.