# keep variable or target entire class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Assuming I have a jQuery click handler for a certain `class`, where multiple buttons/bodies/section have that class. I want to know which button was clicked last, unclick any previously clicked button, and make it obvious to the client as well.

What is a better approach, keep track of a variable for the last clicked button so I can change it to 'unclicked' when another one is clicked, or just target the entire class?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ou1wy5vt/1/)

part of why I ask is because if I target the entire class, and remove a style or class from all those objects, it requires less code, however, I'm modifying many elements. But if I keep a variable, I'm only modifying 2 elements, the one that was already clicked, and the one that just got clicked on.

however, keeping a variable means having to add conditional logic that isn't required if I just say "remove class 'clicked' from all 'buttons'". So as far as performance, is there one way that's better or are they relatively equivalent?

Comment: Looks fine the way you're doing it in the demo.

Comment: @tymeJV is there any advantage for one way vs another?

Comment: Just use `$('.button.clicked').removeClass('clicked')`. That's pretty fast and I don't think the *speed* difference will affect your application.

Answer (score 3):

Global or locally scoped variables, holding state, are best avoided if you can.

For this type of scenario I would target the classes (fast selector). Exclude the current item from the clearing of classes and toggle the target. This allows for on/off too.

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').on('click', function() {
        $('.button').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ou1wy5vt/2/

You will not care about any speed differences, unless you click 50,000 times a second, but if you want a fast selector, without caching it, this is a tad fast as it will have less results:

```
$('.clicked').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
```

or, cache the jQuery selector:

```
$(function() {
    var $buttons = $('.button').on('click', function() {
        $buttons.not(this).removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

*Again though, you want the simplest, easiest to read/maintain option, rather than trying to be too clever/fast and losing maintainability.*

Comment: If speed is an issue : `$('.button.clicked').not(this).removeClass('clicked');`.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon: Since when is a single click event *ever* a speed issue! :)

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon:: Actually a single class selector is faster than your example, as it hits the browser cache direct. Almost as fast as an ID search on modern browsers. Your example will match all `.clicked` and then `filter` against `.button`.

Comment: Yeah there is no issue at all :) But I understand the single class selector is faster during the selection, but doesn't it slow the process of the `.not()` and `.removeClass()` since there is an internal loop (in the `.removeClass()` atleast)? Of course, it doesn't really matter, it is just for personal knowledge.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon: Bizzarely, tests of jquery `each` against a `for (var i = 0; i< count; i++)` actually have jQuery outperform a standard loop. Counter-intuitive, but there is something rather cool going on under the hood. I would avoid state-based `var` coding in preference to self-contained anyway. It ports to multiple control scenarios, but a single state var won't. Again though speed is not an issue here :)

Comment: jQuery's `each` can't be faster than a `for` loop... because `each` uses `for ( ; i < length; i++ )` internally.

Comment: @Oriol: you *would* think so.. I will have to dig out the JSPerfs I was shown.

Comment: @Oriol: It looks like the tests used were misleading, but it actually depends on *what* is in the loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808144/each-vs-each-vs-for-loop-in-jquery you may find it interesting.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Interesting, thanks. But as explained by the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14808730/1529630), `for` loops are much faster if measured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you target the entire class, all elements in that class will be iterated, and jQuery will attempt to remove the class for each one, even if they don't have it.

Therefore, keeping track of the previous clicked button is faster, because you only remove the class of the desired element.

It would be even faster if you stored the jQuery element wrapper:

```js
var $clicked = $();
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $clicked.removeClass('clicked');
    $clicked = $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Again with the scare-mongering... speed is a non-issue for a single click event. If they were clicking 50,000 times a second this would make a difference. :)

Comment: What if the number of `.button` elements (`n`) is e.g. 1 billion, and this runs on a smartphone with only 0.0001% battery remaining? An `O(1)` algorithm will always be better than an `O(n)`.

Comment: Use a delegated event handler for starters! :) If you check my later updates you will see it is also `O(1)` :P

Comment: Your code is still `O(n)`: `$.fn.not` calls `winnow` which calls `$.grep` which does `for ( ; i < length; i++ )`.

Comment: I say black. You say white. A class selector with a single match is a) almost as fast as an id selector and b) iterates on only one item so is not O(n).

Comment: A class selector iterates all the subtree of the context node. It's fast because it's native, but IDs are much faster: since they are unique, they can be stored in a hash table and be retrieved in `O(1)` in average (if using `getElementById`, not `querySelector`). Your `$buttons.not(this)` iterates all the `$buttons` array-like in JS speed.

Comment: I have seen the perfs. Class selectors are almost as fast as Id selectors on modern browsers. Using the wrong example from  my question is no way to prove your point. :) bored now so going.