# My $.each loop is quite slow. Any methods of making it faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a chrome extension that needs to look through every `<p></p>` on a webpage. My chrome extension looks at the `p` text and checks if the text is located in an array. The problem is, the array has over 3,000 elements and I'd quite like to get that up to 12,000 or more if possible.

At the current rate, that just isn't feasible because it takes the webpage about 4 extra seconds to load the page. My chrome extension runs at the end of the document so the user can technically browse the site, it just takes 4 seconds for everything to load.

Here is my code:

```
$.each(arrayObj, function(key, value) {
      $("p").highlight(key, {caseSensitive: true, className: 'highlight-882312', wordsOnly:true });
});

$('.highlight-882312').each(function() {    

    var currentKey = $(this).text();
    console.log(currentKey);

//do something else here that doesn't really 
//apply to the question as it only runs when the user hovers over the class.

});
```

and then the array looks pretty simple like this:

```
var arrayObj = {

"keyword1": 'keyword_1_site',
"keyword2": 'keyword_2_site',
... etc
... 3,000+ more lines ...
...

}
```

I'm assuming `$.each` isn't the most efficient, and as I said, 4 seconds to load is quite a bit. Is there anything I could do to make this more efficient? Will I ever be able to hit 12,000 lines in the array?

Thanks :)

Comment: if you need a search method you can use some research algorithm, like dichotomic search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var p = $("p");
$.each(arrayObj, function(key, value) {
  p.highlight(key, {caseSensitive: true, className: 'highlight-882312', wordsOnly:true });
});

$('.highlight-882312').each(function(idx, element) {    
  var currentKey = element.text();
  console.log(currentKey);

  // other stuff
});
```

Generally speaking, you want to avoid `$()` selectors inside loops as they're time consuming. Notice that `each()`'s callback receives the element that's being iterated and you don't need to select it again.

This solution might not completely solve your problem but at least is the most efficient way to do it that I can think of without knowing more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ideas :

- `$("p")` and the `.highlight()` options are static, so define once, use many.
- apply `.highlight()` only to those words that actually exist on the page.

```
var options = {
        caseSensitive: true,
        className: 'highlight-882312',
        wordsOnly:true
    },
    arrayObj_ = {},
    $p = $("p");

//Populate arrayObj_ with true for every word that exists on the page
$p.each(function() {
    $(this).text().split(' ').forEach(function(word) {
        arrayObj_[word] = true;
    });
});

//Now loop through arrayObj_ ,
// which is hopefully much smaller than arrayObj,
// and highlight those words that are represted as keys in arrayObj.
$.each(arrayObj_, function(key, value) {
    if(arrayObj[key]) {
        $p.highlight(key, options);
    }
});
```

No idea whether this will be faster or slower. You will need to run tests.

Edit ...

Even better, discover words and highlight in a single pass.

```
var options = {
        caseSensitive: true,
        className: 'highlight-882312',
        wordsOnly:true
    },
    wordsFound = {},
    $p = $("p");

$p.text().split(/\b/).forEach(function(word) {
    if(!wordsFound[word]) {
        wordsFound[word] = true;
        if(arrayObj[word]) {
            $p.highlight(word, options);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor them to javascript `for` loop instead of jQuery's `each` loops.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808512/1547497

i.e.

```
var elems = $('.highlight-882312');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i){

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert my `each` array to a for loop but it doesn't seem to work out for me.. Could you guide me into the right direction based off of my `each` loop in the post?

Comment: The overhead caused by jQuery's `each` method on that block is a minor concern comparing to the previous iteration that makes a `$()` selection on each loop... In my answer I propose a different strategy that avoids such operations.

Answer (score 0):

You are running global selectors for each element in array. That's quite a lot.

So at least I would suggest to replace this:

```
$.each(arrayObj, function(key, value) {
      $("p").highlight(key, ...);
});
```

by this:

```
var $all_p = $("p");

$.each(arrayObj, function(key, value) {
    $all_p.highlight(key, ...);
});
```