# $.each() over Key value pair array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've created my array as following:

```
var test = [];
test['pizza'] = 4;
test['pudding'] = 6;
```

I'm used to use `$.each` to loop over my array and print out the values and indexes. I'm doing this as following:

```
$.each(test, function (index, value){
    console.log(value); 
});
```

Yet somehow it does only print `[]`.
How would one loop through an array as mine to print out the values `4` and `6`?

Comment: `console.log(test['pizza']);
console.log(test['pudding']);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each` will only iterate over iterable properties of the array, `pizza` and `pudding` are not iterable properties.

As you require the key-value pair, declare the variable as object.

```
var test = {};
test['pizza'] = 4;
test['pudding'] = 6;
```

Comment: Soo iterable properties are arrays with key 0,1,2,3 etc right?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to iterate through a Javascript array, just use `for`.

```
var test = [];
test['pizza'] = 4;
test['pudding'] = 6;

for (var k in test) {
    if (test.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        console.log('Key: ' + k + ' Value: ' + test[k]);
    }
}

// Key: pizza Value: 4
// Key: pudding Value: 6
```

**You don't need to declare test as an object for this (suggested in other answers), array is fine.**

By using `for` you are improving performance of your application. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808730/381802).

> In both Firefox and Chrome, the for loop is well over 100x faster than
>   the others.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to choose what happens to serve your needs. I guess you were trying to get a array of objects which will look something like [{},{},{},{}]

Answer (score 0):

Here test is an object(Associative array), not an array so you need to declare it as javascript object

```
var test = {};
test['pizza'] = 4;
test['pudding'] = 6;

$.each(test, function (index, value){
    console.log(value); 
});
```