# What's the difference between jQuery $().each() and implicit iteration?

Tags: jquery, each

I have two inputs from two separate search forms of the same page. One has `data-result-select-url` attribute and one doesn't.

```
<input id="q_id_eq" class="foo" type="text" size="30" name="q[id_eq]" data-result-select-url="/products/(id)" tabindex="-1"></input>

<input id="q_id_eq" class="foo" type="text" size="30" name="q[id_eq]" tabindex="-1"></input>
```

I write my own select2 plugin for these inputs.

```
$ = jQuery
$.fn.my_select2 = (args) ->
  ...
  select_url = $(this).data("result-select-url")
  if select_url?
    $(this).on "change", (e) ->
      ...

  $(this).select2 args
```

When I use `$().each()` to call my plugiin `my_select2()`, this works fine.  Only one input receives the "changed" event.

```
jQuery
  $('.foo').each ->
    $(this).my_select2()
```

But if I call my_select2() using jQuery implicit iterations, both inputs receive the event.

```
jQuery ->
  $('.foo').my_select2()
```

What is the explanation?  I looked up [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for `each` but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$.each(\[collection\]) vs $(\[collection\]).each()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321520/eachcollection-vs-collection-each)

Comment: No, it's different.  I'm asking the difference between explicit iteration using `$('.foo').each -> $(this).method()` vs implicit iteration `$('.foo').method()`.  I'm not asking difference between `$.each` vs `$().each`

Comment: Your plugin code is incorrect. Within the plugin _this_ is the whole jQuery object, so if you need to test an attribute on the individual DOM elements your plugin should use a loop.